# AssertListEqual without changing class __eq__ method

Tags: python, python-unittest

Let's say I have the following code

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.attr1 = val1
        self.attr2 = val2

class MySecondClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def add_to_list(self, val1, val2):
        self.my_list.append(MyClass(val1, val2))
```

and the following unit-testing code

```
import unittest

def myclass_equality(inst1, inst2, msg=None):
    val1_matches = inst1.val1 == inst2.val1
    val2_matches = inst1.val2 == inst2.val2
    if not val1_matches or not val2_matches:
        raise unittest.TestCase.failureException(msg)

class ListTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListTests, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(MyClass, myclass_equality)

    def setUp(self):
        self.second = MySecondClass()

    def test_adding_to_list(self):
        val1, val2 = 1, 2
        self.second.add_to_list(val1, val2)
        my_other_list = [(MyClass(val1, val2))]
        self.assertListEqual(self.second.my_list, my_other_list)
```

However, the assertion fails as the assertListEqual method compares objects with '==' as can be seen [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/14cafb8d1480/Lib/unittest/case.py#l621) and not with the method I have defined, which is called if I call assertEqual on two MyClass instances.

Are there any workarounds? Because I don't need and want to define __eq__ method for MyClass.

And why assertListEqual compares with '==' and not assertEqual?

Comment: In your code, you call assertItemsEqual, but then you mention assertListEqual. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am fixing this (it's the same problem though).

Comment: You mean MyClass instead of MySecondClass in the second last line?

Comment: It seems that there has already been some discussion about this [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue22452).

Comment: Hmm I see. Thank you. Maybe I can use [testfixtures](https://pythonhosted.org/testfixtures/comparing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do it in a loop or create another loop wrapper for your `myclass_equality` function? I feel like I am missing something.

E.g.:

```
def test_adding_to_list(self):
    val1, val2 = 1, 2
    self.second.add_to_list(val1, val2)
    my_other_list = [(MyClass(val1, val2))]
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(self.second.my_list, my_other_list)):
        myclass_equality(a, b, msg='Adding to list failed on element {}:{}!={}'.format(i, a, b)
```

Comment: But with something more complex? And if I want to avoid repetition? After all there is already something that does nearly what I want so I though I ask. But you are right it can be done this way.

Comment: To make it DRY you would put that logic into a list version of `myclass_equality`. If you don't want to implement `__eq__` it seems you would need to basically make a bugfix for the issue linked by user "import this" or wrap `TestCase.assertSequenceEqual` to do your custom comparison when the sequence contains your object type before doing the standard comparison.